# sound played when a key character appears

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the name for the music or sound played when a key character appears in a play, movie or show; like in "Peter and the Wolf"?

Comment: The [Shaft](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cEaRCAcfOEQ) leitmotif is another familiar example.

Comment: In [Family Guy season 3 episode 21, aka *Viewer Mail #1*](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080530053331AA1gtca) Peter says to the wish-granting genie *"I wish I had my own **theme music**."*.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think the word you're looking for is ***leitmotif***:

> A recurrent theme throughout a musical or literary composition, associated with a particular person, idea, or situation.
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/leitmotif)

Comment: Thank you Andrew and thank you "English Language & Usage" for creating this forum. I could not remember that term and searching had not brought results.

Answer (score 7):

The tune associated with a particular character is called that character's ***musical theme***, ***theme music***, or ***[signature song](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_song)***.

From the [Wikipedia article on *Peter and the Wolf*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_and_the_Wolf), for example:

> *Each character in the story has a particular instrument and a **musical theme**:*
>
> **Bird**: *flute*
>   **Cat**: *clarinet*
>   **Duck**: *oboe*
>   **Grandfather**: *bassoon*
>   **Hunters**: *woodwind theme, with gunshots on timpani and bass drum*
>   **Peter**:  *instruments (including violin, viola, cello, and bass)*
>   **Wolf**: *French horns*

And similarly, quoting from the [Wikipedia article on "theme music"](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theme_music):

> *The phrase **theme song** or **signature tune** may also be used to refer to a signature song that has become especially associated with a particular performer or **dignitary; often used as they make an entrance***.

Comment: +1 as although *leitmotif* is the technical term, many people refer to it as a character's *theme*, particularly for film soundtracks; it also appears in some song titles, e.g. *[Princess Leia's Theme](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Princess_Leia%27s_Theme)*, *[Yoda's Theme](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda%27s_Theme)*.

Answer (score 3):

I think I may have found it: "leitmotif."

From the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leitmotif) entry a leitmotif is "is a "short, constantly recurring musical phrase" associated with a particular person, place, or idea."

Comment: Indeed, that is the term. I encourage you to improve this answer by excerpting a definition and linking to an authoritative reference, and then you will have my upvote. For additional guidance, I encourage you to visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Except that it's poor form to repeat an answer already given.

Answer (score 1):

Although several answers have identified "leitmotif," if the music in question is more brief it could be called a

> fanfare

or

> flourish

OED describes a [fanfare](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fanfare) as:

> A short ceremonial tune or flourish played on brass instruments, typically to introduce something or someone important: a specially composed fanfare announced the arrival of the Duchess

The relevant definition for [flourish](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flourish) cites "fanfare" but another definition provides color:

> A bold or extravagant gesture or action, made especially to attract attention: with a flourish, she ushered them inside

Answer (score 1):

[**theme**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theme_(music)) - This is probably what I would choose.  Example: "Did you hear how [Leia's Theme](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Princess_Leia%27s_Theme) came in just then when they mentioned her?"

[**motif**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theme_(music)) or **motive** (less common) - This would probably be my second choice.  It's a general musical term, basically synonymous with theme.

[**leitmotif**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motif_(music)) - Has a specific technical meaning in music theory.  While all leitmotifs are themes used to represent characters and ideas, not all such motifs are commonly called leitmotifs, since leitmotif carries connotations of a certain musical tradition, from [Richard Wagner](http://www.utexas.edu/courses/tristan/motives.php) to the [Lord of the Rings](http://www.woodzie.org/lotr/) soundtrack.  If you're looking for something general, this is not necessarily the best word to choose.  The word also may not be as recognizable to a wider audience.